# Python instagram scrape suggestions

Tags: python, web-scraping

So I'm trying to scrape some data from instagram, mainly suggestions. As it turns out it's fetching suggestions from 'instagram.com/query/' by sending there some formatted data. But when I try to replicate the process it returns forbidden (403) status, returning "This page could not be loaded. If you have cookies disabled in your browser, or you are browsing in Private Mode, please try enabling cookies or turning off Private Mode, and then retrying your action.", this error text. How can I proceed?

I'm using requests package to access it, and I'm replicating cookies,headers and data completely.

Edit: I fixed the issue by adding 'referer' field into the headers, but now I have different issue. It returns "{"status": "fail", "message": "syntax error"}" instead of desired json. 
I'm sending     `payload = dict(q='ig_user(182989637){chaining{nodes{blocked_by_viewer,followed_by_viewer,follows_viewer,full_name,has_blocked_viewer,has_requested_viewer,id,is_private,is_verified,profile_pic_url,requested_by_viewer,username}}',ref='',query_id='17843133337188024')`
this as payload.

Comment: Did you try looking into the instagram [API](https://www.instagram.com/developer/)?

Comment: There is no endpoint for suggestions in api I think

Comment: Got it. Can you show us the POST request header and the data that you are trying to send? From what I see, it has a CSRF token attached to its request.

Comment: I fixed it but I have different issue now

Comment: Post the answer for your fix so you can close this question

Comment: I have different issue now tho

Comment: @JukesOnYou Any news here? My scripts got broken recently, I'm receiving `{'status': 'fail', 'message': 'invalid parameters'}`